# Android Navigation Drawer implemented with Activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-navigation

I am developing my own Android Application and i came to a point where i have three different Activities say Activity A, Activity B and Activity C. What i want to do now is to create a Navigation Drawer to navigate between them. I read the tutorial on the Android Developers website but they only focused on Fragments. How are professional Android Applications developed only with one Activity and all the other screens are developed with the use of Fragments?If not why isn't documented how to implement correct the navigation drawer with Activities instead?Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note that the documentation is saying that you should only use a navigation drawer in case you have more than three top level view.

Comment: Ok to make it more specific how is the Google Play Store developed in terms of Navigation Drawer?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to create a `Base activity` which does all the common `Drawer navigation` stuff . I will call this base `Activity` as `DrawerActivity` , and all other `Activity` should extend this `DrawerActivity` . So all the `Activity` will have one  instance of `Drawer Layout`.

Create a common Layout with `DrawerLayout` and place a `FrameLayout` and `ListView` as child

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_frame”/>
   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer”/>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now set this Layout in `onCreate()` on `DrawerActivity`

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_layout);
   // do other stuff to initialize drawer layout, add list items
  ……… 
   ……….
  // add a listener to the drawer list view 
 mLeftDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

}

Add a item click listener

```
  private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DrawerActivity.this, YourActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLeftDrawerList);
    }
}
```

Finally, All the  other activity will extend this `DrawerActivity`

```
 public class MainActivity extends DrawerActivity {

   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // don’t set any content view here, since its already set in DrawerActivity
   FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_frame);
    // inflate the custom activity layout
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View activityView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null,false);
    // add the custom layout of this activity to frame layout.
    frameLayout.addView(activityView);
    // now you can do all your other stuffs
    }
 }
```

You can see the complete source here https://gist.github.com/libinbensin/613dea436302d3015563

Comment: Please provide an complete example of an activity that extends DrawerActivity. I inflated my layout and added that as childview of the frame layout. But it doesn't work. I just need (// add your custom layout of this activity to frame layout.) , how to do that correctly.

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to `inflate` your `Activity` layout and add its as a child to the `FrameLayout`. Let me know if you still see any issue

Comment: Ahh... I did exactly same code , but I set frameLayout as ViewGroup parameter for inflating the layout. Probably that was the reason why my app seems to fall in infinite loop. I'll try it , if that works it will be a great help.Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Libin how to prevent opening current activity twice ?

Answer (score -5):

You can have a NavigationDrawer in each Activity, populated with the same list of options.

Comment: I have thought about that but is this a common practice?